# Provide Integral Image to CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

Tags: opencv

According to the [documentation of OpenCV Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-setimage%20documentation) `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()` computes the integral image of the provided image, which makes sense.

Now wouldn't it be a nice thing to compute the integral image once for the image and **provide this integral image to multiple different cascade classifiers**?

Documentation says further:

> Note
>
> in the old API you need to supply integral images (that can be obtained using Integral()) instead of the original image.

**My question:** Is there a hidden (or undocumented) way to still provide integral images to the classifier instead of grayscale images?